# Unable to get "LINE Access Token" from Login API

Tags: c#, asp.net, line

I am trying to Send and Receive LINE messages through LINE API. But I am unable to get the Access Token from the LINE.

I had successfully got the Code, but not able to Generate the Access token from that.

```
Response.Redirect("https://access.line.me/dialog/oauth/weblogin?response_type=code&client_id=" + line_messages_api.client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + callbackurl + "&state=123abc");
```

This Gives the Code Successfully, which I am trying to post to get the Access Token as:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
        {
            line_messages_api.accessToken(Request.QueryString["code"], callbackurl);
        }
    }

public static void accessToken(string code, string redirect_url)
{
    string url = "https://api.line.me/v2/oauth/accessToken";
    string query = "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_url;
    var se = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string response = PostRequest(url, query);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
    {
        cl_line_AccessToken tok = se.Deserialize<cl_line_AccessToken>(response);
        if (tok.scope == "P" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tok.access_token))
        {
            access_token = tok.access_token;
            refersh_token = tok.refresh_token;
        }
    }
}
```

Response Here is empty. **Any Help regarding here will be appreciated.**